# window.addEventListener does not work

Tags: javascript, iframe, postmessage

I am trying to send a `<div>` height from an `<iframe>` to its parent (cross domains):

**Child page code (iframe):**

```
<script>
   var h = $('#frame').height();
   parent.postMessage(h, '*');
<script>
```

**The parent page:**

```
<script>
    window.addEventListener("message",
        function (e) {              
            alert(e.data);
        },
        false
    );
</script>
```

I tested in `chrome` and `IE11` without success!

Here is my test page:
http://pulse.org.il/test.html

Comment: is the content of `iframe` from same domain?

Comment: no, it's cross domains

Comment: Depending on the 10000 alerts i get on your page, I assume it works?

Comment: yes same here. works fine for me. did you checked your browser console if any error there?

Comment: Strange, I don't see the alert...